# Will an Ubuntu distro in place upgrade disrupt my Mathematica installation?

Tags: linux, installation, licensing

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu based distribution to the latest distro but I am unsure of the effect on the licencing on my machine.  Will upgrading my distribution require me to call Wolfram Support to change my licence?

Comment: In my experience (now a long time ago, Oneiric(?) was still new), upgrading Ubuntu did not disrupt my license, but even if it did, the people from Support are usually very helpful with sending a new key if things went pear-shaped for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've upgraded 14.04 → 16.04, then 16.04 → 18.04 without issue.

In the case of genuine system reinstallations, technical support have responded within 24 hours, during which time I'm usually installing other things.

Comment: Can confirm 19.10 --> 20.04 works fine also.

Comment: Good to know @jman.  I'll wait until 20.04.1 before dist-upgrade.